# How to save token from Alamofire response in swift

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I'm learning swift currently, so I apologize for the softball.  My goal here is to create and display an API response in an app.  My first step is to get an access token.  The next step is to use that token in an API call to get the data I want.

I can get the initial call to work using AlamoFire.  I can also get the response and parse it for the token.  However, I can't seem to save that token outside of the function which means I can't make my second call.

From what I'm reading, I need to use a struct to assign the api response to a globally accessable variable, but it seems I'm still missing something as I can't seem to assign a value to a variable via the struct. I'm attempting to output the Token to the screen as proof that I have saved the token in a globally accessible location.  The attempted location is at the bottom at `resultstext.text = temptext + tempstore + ???token`.  However, it won't let me call access_token or token as those are "unresolved identifiers".  I've fought this off and on for several days and I need a push here to get this going again.

1. Is this the best way to do this?
2. If so, what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for any insight!

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var partnumberlabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var partnumberentry: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var storelabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var storeentry: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var resultstext: UILabel!

    struct Tken: Codable {
        let access_token: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case access_token = "access_token"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()     
    }

    @IBAction func submitbutton(_ sender: Any) {
        let headers:HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.20.1",
            "Accept": "*/*",
            "Host": "api.xxx.xxx",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
            "Content-Length": "206",
            "Connection": "keep-alive"
        ]
 
        let params = [
            "client_id": "xxx",
            "client_secret": "xxx",
            "account": "xxx",
            "user": "xxx",
            "grant_type": "xxx",
            "scope": "xxx"
        ]

        let token_url = "https://api.xxx.xxx/auth/connect/token"
        
        AF.request(token_url, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let JSON):
                print("button tapped")
                let response = JSON as! NSDictionary
                let token = response.object(forKey: "access_token") as! String?
                do {
                    let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Tken.self, from: JSON as! Data)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
                print(token!)
                print("the end")

            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }   
        }
        let temptext = partnumberentry.text!
        let tempstore = storeentry.text!
        resultstext.text = temptext + tempstore + ???token
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't simply cast `JSON as! Data`. You have to encode it.

Comment: Thanks @Frankenstein.  I initially had it like this: ```let res = try JSONDecoder().decode(Tken.self, from: JSON)``` assuming that the .responseJSON would have it encoded on the end of the AF call.  But xcode rejected that.  I'll read up on how to encode it, but I thought it already was from the AF call.